# How to print a value of parameter inside of function in Unix Korn Shell

Tags: function, shell, variables, unix, ksh

I'm trying to print a value inside a function. But it is not working; it is printing the variable name.  Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
MyVariable=""

function ValidateVariableValue
{
   eval $1="Working!"
   echo "$1"  #Here is printing the value "MyVariable" instead of "Working!"
}

ValidateVariableValue MyVariable

echo "value is: ${MyVariable}" #Here is printing the correct value that is "Working!"
```

Do you know how print the value inside the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call your function, the positional variable `$1` is set to MyVariable.

The statement

```
eval $1="Working!"
```

is creating a new variable whose name is contained in `$1`.  In your case, `MyVariable`.

So, `echo "$1"` is correctly printing the value of `$1` which is `MyVariable`.  You need to use `eval` to print the value of the new variable:

```
eval "echo \$$1"
```

---

See this post on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange:

- [Use a variable reference inside another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/use-a-variable-reference-inside-another-variable)